# Functions on the cotangent bundle of general complete intersection of quadrics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a general complete intersection of $n$ quadrics in $\mathbb{P}(V)$, where $V$ is a complex vector space of dimension $2n+1$. Let $N$ be the subspace generated by the $n-$quadrics in $S^2(V^*)$. Then there is natural map $N \to H^0(X, S^2(T^* \otimes \mathcal{O}(1)))$, where $T^*$ denotes the cotangent bundle of $X$, which induces a map $N \to H^0(X, S^2(\Lambda^{n-1}T^* \otimes \mathcal{O}(n-1)))$. Identifying $\Lambda^{n-1}T^*$ with $T \otimes K_X^*$ and composing with the evaluation map, we get a map $N \to S^2T \otimes \mathcal{O}(n-2)$.

Question: Does the above map induces a flat surjective map from $T^*X \to N^*$ ?complex

Comment: I don't understand your question. Also, did you check the cases $n = 1$ and $n = 2$?

Comment: The case $n=2$ has been studied by HOSUNG KIM AND YONGNAM LEE https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.01317. In fact they have proved that $T^*X \to \mathbb{C}^2$ is Lagrangian fibration.

Comment: For $n=1$ the map $N \to H^0(X, S^2(T^* \otimes \mathcal{O}(1)))$ gives a nonzero section of $S^2T$, which can be thought as a function on $T^*X$.

Comment: For $n=1$ $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$,  $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1,S^2T)$ is the space of quartic polynomials, which one do you get???

Comment: May be I am wrong. But in this case also we will get a flat surjective map from $T^*X \to \mathbb{C}$. Basically I want a flat surjective map $T^*X \to \mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Such a map is given by elements of $H^0(X, \operatorname{Sym}^{\bullet}T_X )$, but this is zero as soon as $n\geq 4$.

Comment: Is it true for $n=3$  ?

Comment: I think it is still true (that $H^0(X,\operatorname{Sym}^{p}T_X )=0$ for $p>0$), but I haven't checked.